# Colorize the thead and the odd row in a table in different colors

Tags: html, css

I need to colorize the background of the thead tr in black and the odd table rows in lightgreen. I don't use CSS classes, only HTML elements.

So, I use `tr:nth-child(odd)` with `table thead tr` that didn't work for the latter, as the `:` has upper priority than the element names.

So it seems for me impossible to do it without "hacking" the `thead:first-child` (that is obvious, there are no multiple theads in a table).

```css
   
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: lightgreen; }

table thead:first-child tr { background-color: black; color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>City</td></tr> <!-- Green on Black -->
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 1</td><td>London</td></tr> <!-- Black on Green -->
    <tr><td>row 2</td><td>Paris</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3</td><td>Munich</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td><td>Kiev</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 5</td><td>Amsterdam</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there more elegant way to do it?

Comment: what would be wrong with `tbody tr:nth...` to filter thead ? or `not:(thead) tr:nth-..`

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is no more elegant way to do it than this:

```css
table thead tr { background-color: black; color: lightgreen; }
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>City</td></tr> <!-- Green on Black -->
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 1</td><td>London</td></tr> <!-- Black on Green -->
    <tr><td>row 2</td><td>Paris</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3</td><td>Munich</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td><td>Kiev</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 5</td><td>Amsterdam</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, adding the full selector gives it a higher priority.

Comment: is not about priority, he just excluded other that tbody rows... so, for `tfoot` I should add another class then ;) ?

Comment: @Serge Yes, for `tfoot` you have to add `table tfoot tr {blabla}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, but it doesn't really make a difference I guess.

```css
   
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: lightgreen; }

th { background-color: black; color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>City</th></tr> <!-- Green on Black -->
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 1</td><td>London</td></tr> <!-- Black on Green -->
    <tr><td>row 2</td><td>Paris</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3</td><td>Munich</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td><td>Kiev</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 5</td><td>Amsterdam</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```